# React - Form submit button in parent Modal

Tags: reactjs, forms, modal-dialog, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a Semantic UI Form:

```
import {Form} from 'semantic-ui-react';

<MyForm>
    <Form onSubmit={_handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Input name="myInput" label="My Label" value="" />
        <Form.Group>
            <Form.Button>Submit</Form.Button>
        </Form.Group>
    </Form>
</MyForm>
```

**This form can be displayed inside a modal, or directly in a standard view in my app**

My modal looks like this:

```
import {Button, Modal} from 'semantic-ui-react';

<Modal open={true} size="large" centered>
    <Modal.Header>My Label</Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Content>
        <MyForm />
    </Modal.Content>
    <Modal.Actions>
        <Button className="close-button">Cancel</Button>
        {/* Insert submit button here*/}
    </Modal.Actions>
</Modal>
```

This simple approach is working.

What I would like to do, is to have **the submit button inside the `Modal.Actions` section when it's displayed in a modal**, and keep it right after the input otherwise.

I don't know how to tell my form that the submit button is somewhere in its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it using a ref.
The idea is to create a ref in the form, pointing to the submit function and having a function in props to transmit this ref to my modal.

Modal:

```
import {Button, Modal} from 'semantic-ui-react';

const [submitFunc, setSubmitFunc] = useState();
const submitForm = () => {
    if (submitFunc) {
        submitFunc.current();
    }
};

<Modal open={true} size="large" centered>
    <Modal.Header>My Label</Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Content>
        <MyForm setSubmitFunc={setSubmitFunc} />
    </Modal.Content>
    <Modal.Actions>
        <Button>Cancel</Button>
        <Button onClick={submitForm}>Submit</Button>
    </Modal.Actions>
</Modal>
```

Form:

```
function EditRecordForm({setSubmitFunc}) {
    const submitRef = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!!setSubmitFunc) {
            setSubmitFunc(submitRef);
        }
    });

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        // Do whatever you need to retrieve form values and submit it
    }
    submitRef.current = handleSubmit;

    return (
        <MyForm>
            <Form onSubmit={_handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Input name="myInput" label="My Label" value="" />
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Button>Submit</Form.Button>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </MyForm>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is, you can associate the form with the button in the modal actions using a form id. Here is how you do it :-

Form:

```
<MyForm>
   <Form id={'my-form'} onSubmit={_handleSubmit}>
       {/*Form Elements}
   </Form> 
</MyForm>
```

Modal:

```
 <Modal.Actions>
    <Button>Cancel</Button>
    <Button type={'submit'} form={'my-form'}>Submit</Button>
</Modal.Actions>
```

Following link is the tweet by the creator of chakr-ui telling the same method to join the form in a side drawer which needs to be connected to the button in the drawer footer.

https://twitter.com/thesegunadebayo/status/1330866834636201987?lang=en